# Is it safe to allow a user to write to another user's data?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been reading up on Firebase rules and some of the methods on how to protect data and things of that sort. I have a Firebase RealTimeDatabase (with basic if user is authenticated then read/write rules allow for read/writes) that has a structure like this:

```
"MyApp"{

     "Users"{

         "EXAMPLEUID1"{
                 Name: joe snow
                 Bio: i am joe snow
                 Email: joesnow@fakeemail.com
                 Coins: 900
         }

         "EXAMPLEUID2"{
                 Name: jane snow
                 Bio: i am jane snow
                 Email: janesnow@fakeemail.com
                 Coins: 134
         }

     }
}
```

Lets say that in my app i have a button that allows the user Jane Snow to give 100 of her coins to John Snow. I know that I am allowing Jane Snow to have read/write access to John Snows user node to be able to give him coins, but it also gives read/write access to everything else in his node.

**Is this a risky practice?**

In my app there is no way to allow any user to see any other user's email, much less update it or change it (because i don't display the information in the app), So I can't see how this is an unsafe practice. Any help/advice would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rules allow some unwanted read or write, then you simply have to assume the risk of that happening.  It doesn't matter if your code performs that operation directly.  All that matters is that the authenticated user can do it if they want.  They can simply use the Firebase REST API to access the database directly with their own credentials, bypassing the app completely.  There's nothing you can do to prevent this, as long as you allow reads and writes through security rules.

Whether or not this will ever happen in practice is uncertain, but the fact that it's possible means you have to assume that it *could* happen.  This is why many people choose to write backend code to more clearly express what can and can't happen in various scenarios.

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for. Thanks! One quick question however. Would you recommend moving a users coins to a separate node that could be read/write by anybody and just store a historical value inside of the user's private node in case of unwanted read/writes?

Comment: If you want to do this safely with security rules, my understanding is that you have a LOT of rules to write, which is outside my area of expertise.  With something complicated like a transaction, I would do this with backend code.